# How to select multiple nodes in single for-eachin XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to learn XSLT but I work best by example. I want to perform a trivial schema to schema transformation. How do I perform this transformation in only one pass (my current solution uses two passes and loses the original order of customers)?

From:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sampleroot>

<badcustomer>
    <name>Donald</name>
    <address>Hong Kong</address>
    <age>72</age>
</badcustomer>

<goodcustomer>
    <name>Jim</name>
    <address>Wales</address>
    <age>22</age>
</goodcustomer>

<goodcustomer>
    <name>Albert</name>
    <address>France</address>
    <age>51</age>
</goodcustomer>

</sampleroot>
```

To :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>

<record id="customer">
    <name>Donald</name>
    <address>Hong Kong</address>
    <age>72</age>
    <customertype>bad</customertype>
</record>

<record id="customer">
    <name>Jim</name>
    <address>Wales</address>
    <age>22</age>
    <customertype>good</customertype>
</record>

<record id="customer">
    <name>Albert</name>
    <address>France</address>
    <age>51</age>
    <customertype>good</customertype>
</record>

</records>
```

I already solved this a ***bad*** way (I lose the order of customers and I think that I have to parse the file multiple times:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/sampleroot">

    <records>

        <xsl:for-each select="goodcustomer">
            <record id="customer">
                <name><xsl:value-of select="name" /></name>
                <address><xsl:value-of select="address" /></address>
                <age><xsl:value-of select="age" /></age>
                <customertype>good</customertype>
            </record>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="badcustomer">
            <record id="customer">
                <name><xsl:value-of select="name" /></name>
                <address><xsl:value-of select="address" /></address>
                <age><xsl:value-of select="age" /></age>
                <customertype>bad</customertype>
            </record>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </records>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please can someone help me out with the correct XSLT construct where I only have to use a single parse (only one for-each)?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Good Question Chris (+1). See my answer for a good solution. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**It is a good XSLT practice to avoid using `<xsl:for-each>` as much as possible**.

**Here is a simple solution, using this principle**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <records>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </records>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="badcustomer | goodcustomer">
  <record>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
   <customertype>
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(name(), 'customer')"/>
   </customertype>
  </record>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Do note**:

1. Only templates and `<xsl:apply-templates>` are used.
2. The use of the identity rule and its overriding wherever necessary. This is one of the most fundamental XSLT design pattern.

Comment: Thanks, can I ask for one final piece of information. If I wish to pass through attributes from the original xml schema, how would I adjust the xslt for this to work?

<badcustomer>
    <name myattribute="attributevalue" >Donald</name>
    <address myattribute2="attributevalue2" >Hong Kong</address>
    <age>72</age>
</badcustomer>

Comment: @Chris: Please, ask this as a new question, with properly formatted code/xml. Also, you are using the word "schema" incorrectly. You are actually referrring to the "source XML document" or to an instance of the schema for that document type.

Comment: Thanks for the information and for correcting my incorrect use of "schema". I figured out how to solve the follow-up question so I won't make a new question now.