# Using XSLT, Need to select child node data based on the Condition

Tags: xml, xslt

From the below XML, I Need to select the "wd:Amount" when "wd:Box_Description" = 'Federal income tax withheld'. I'm bit confused, how to select the required data based on the condition in XSLT.
Can any one help out with XSLT code that i need to include.

```css
                  <wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Filing_Data>
                        <wd:Employee_First_Name>Allison</wd:Employee_First_Name>
                        <wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data>
                            <wd:Box_Description>Federal income tax withheld</wd:Box_Description>
                            <wd:Amount>1030.84</wd:Amount>
                        </wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data>
                        <wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data>
                            <wd:Box_Description>Social security wages</wd:Box_Description>
                            <wd:Amount>7156.25</wd:Amount>
                        </wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data>
                        <wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data>
                            <wd:Box_Description>Social security tax withheld</wd:Box_Description>
                            <wd:Amount>443.69</wd:Amount>
                        </wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data>
                        <wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data>
                            <wd:Box_Description>Medicare wages and tips</wd:Box_Description>
                            <wd:Amount>7156.25</wd:Amount>
                        </wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data>
                        <wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data>
                            <wd:Box_Description>Medicare tax withheld</wd:Box_Description>
                            <wd:Amount>103.77</wd:Amount>
                        </wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data>
                        <wd:EFW2_Deferred_and_Other_Compensation_Data>
                            <wd:Code>DD</wd:Code>
                            <wd:Amount>4513.28</wd:Amount>
                        </wd:EFW2_Deferred_and_Other_Compensation_Data>
                    </wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Filing_Data>
```

Thank You !

Comment: What you show us is not XML: you cannot have a prefix (wd) without binding it to a namespace.

Comment: Hi Michael, This is an workday XML, prefixed with WD. I removed namespace to make it simple. I just need the XPATH to select the data.

Comment: "*I removed namespace to make it simple.*" That only makes it harder to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to select the required data based on the
>   condition in XSLT.

You select it by using a *[predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates)*. In your example, the XPath expression could look like this:

```
/wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Filing_Data/wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data[wd:Box_Description='Federal income tax withheld']/wd:Amount
```

However, this requires the `wd:` prefix to be bound to the same namespace as in the input XML.

Comment: Thank You Michael. This is what i'm looking for. Able to select the required data. Thank you for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. you need to select your node first and then this code can be used inside your select

```
<xsl:if test="Box_Description = 'Federal income tax withheld' or Amount=">
  <!-- "if" stuff (there is no "else" here) -->
</xsl:if>


<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="some Boolean condition">
    <!-- "if" stuff -->
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <!-- "else" stuff -->
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

PS: not tested Syntax may change

Recommend going through some XSLT Tutorial for details

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_if.asp

[To compare two elements(string type) in XSLT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649241/to-compare-two-elementsstring-type-in-xslt)

Updated::

You can use XSLT Template apply template concepts for your need to select many nodes and filter

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2775477/1481690 for some example

Comment: I have 'wd:EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data' in common. I need to select data for every worker box data based on the condition.

Comment: you can use XSLT templates (Via Node) for this. you can select multiple  EFW2_Year_End_Worker_Box_Data nodes  and then filter

Comment: Updated my answer with sample link

Comment: It helps peru. Thank you for your efforts.